Is there a way to add multiple AndroidManifest files in .NET Android Xamarin?
I want to build my .net android application for different Environment so for that I want to use different PackageName in AndroidManifest. Is this possible?
I have tried to put the values in string.xml file but it's not working, I'm updating my values in pipeline.
.Net version .Net8-android not MAUI
